# How to replace the percent character to html sign?

Tags: php, str-replace

I try to replace percent sign in string to html "`&#37;`".
I'm using str_replace:

```
$string  = 'test10%';
str_replace('%', '&#37;', $string);
```

but the result is `&amp;#37`.

Comment: Are you HTML encoding this result later, perhaps...? This code here will most certainly *not* produce and `&amp;`.

Comment: I send it to XMLWriter

Comment: Well, "&#37;" expressed in XML is "&amp;#37", so all is good.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in xmlwriter, but the Web Service provider require to get percentage as `&#37;` and this is way I try to replace original symbol by html reference. Maybe I'm doing it in wrong place? But if I put `%` to xmlwriter, it will be send as `%` not `&#37`.

Comment: Hm... I have moved the str_replace after the `xmlwriter->outputMemory()` and now all works fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your **text** is "&#37;" and you're using `XMLWriter` to write it, then it will make sure that your *text* is correctly expressed as *XML* and will accordingly encode it to `&amp;#37`. That's the correct XML representation of the *text* "&#37;".

What you're trying to do is to write already encoded XML into XML, for which you need to use `XMLWriter::writeRaw`. However, you need to make really sure that all the text you're passing to `XMLWriter::writeRaw` is already correctly XML encoded, since this allows you to break your XML syntax at will. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-write-raw.php

> ... the Web Service provider require to get percentage as `&#37;`

FWIW, that's a terribly stupid thing to require and points to a broken XML parser on their side. Just had to be said.